# How to load data from a external drive into another using a pyboard and mycropython

Tags: python, memory, micropython

I want strap two external drives togther using a pyboard and use a micropython skipt th transfer data between them. Now I need some way read and copy data from one drive and write to the other (or just transfere it in any way) through my pypoard. Thanks for your help ;)

I know how I can open or import files, but I would like to find a more elegent way to maby directly transfere the data.

Comment: Is what your looking for https://github.com/dhylands/rshell ?

Comment: yeah, that is helpfull. Just one more question: How can I maximize the data transmittion rate when using th pins on the side?

Comment: What board are you running MicroPython on? I'm guessing by pins on the side you mean UART and repl over uart?

Comment: I am using the standart MicroPython pyboard v1.1. And I intend to use UART (if there is nothing more suited to my spesific case) to transfer whole files back and forth between two drives and the pyboard.

Comment: Have you tried rshell? It transfers between pc and pyboard and pyboard to pyboard via the usb cable. That runs at 112500 baud.

Comment: Thanks, but my point is that I need to use the UART Pins of the pyboard. Can I use rshell for that as well? And if so, can I expect equal transmition speeds to the usb port?

Comment: rshell uses REPL to work. If you use standard REPL over USB you can have data rates of 112500 baud.  You set the baud for each UART when you initislise it. If your doing REPL over UART i can't offer further assistance.